# get the value of the select box by its attribute name

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I have this HTML

```
<select name="test">
    <option value="" selected disabled>please select</option>
    <option value="option1">option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">option 2</option>
</select>
```

and the way I tried to get the attribute named "value" content of the current selected option in the select box is (assume I have already selected the option 1):

```
alert($("select[name='test'] option:selected", this).val());
```

but it returns me `[object object]`. Any clues or ideas?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/u9Lch5gm/1/ - looks fine... I don't think it will return `[object object]`

Comment: yeah. it change it to "$("select[name='test']", this).val()"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to only use `$("select[name='test']").val()` to get the selected value

```js
$("select[name='test']").change(function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="test">
  <option value="" selected disabled>please select</option>
  <option value="option1">option 1</option>
  <option value="option2">option 2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

The value property of a select box comes from the value attribute of the selected option or the first selected option in a select-multiple type select box. So the value of the selected option can be obtained in JavaScript as follows:

```
// reference to 'category' select list in 'demoForm'
var sel =       document.forms['demoForm'].elements['category'];

// value property of select list (from selected option)
var val = sel.value;
```

If option elements do not contain a value attribute, generally the text content of the option element will be the value property. However, Internet Explorer prior to version 9 will not provide the value in this case. If your option elements do not include value attributes and you wish to support older browsers, for best results use the old-fashioned approach to referencing the selected option and access its text property:

```
// access text property of selected option
var val = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
```

The options property of the select list is a node list of all the option elements contained within it. The selectedIndex property of the select list specifies the location of the selected option in the node list. The text property of an option is the content of the option element.